# Extract values from column of dictionaries using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am trying to extract the name from the below dictionary:

```
df = df[[x.get('Name') for x in df['Contact']]]
```

Given below is how my Dataframe looks like:

```
data = [{'emp_id': 101,
  'name': {'Name': 'Kevin',
   'attributes': {'type': 'Contact',
    'url': '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact/00985300000bt4HEG4'}}},
 {'emp_id': 102,
  'name': {'Name': 'Scott',
   'attributes': {'type': 'Contact',
    'url': '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact/00985300000yr5UTR9'}}}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

   emp_id                                               name
0     101  {'Name': 'Kevin', 'attributes': {'type': 'Cont...
1     102  {'Name': 'Scott', 'attributes': {'type': 'Cont...
```

I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @njzk2,  I am trying to extract the value corresponding to 'Name'

Comment: If this is a dataframe, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @coldspeed, sorry I have updated my initial post with how the Dataframe looks like..

Comment: And what's the result of current code?

Comment: Post the error you get (if any)

Comment: @smac89, edited with the error that I am getting currently..

Comment: Try `pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.name.tolist())['Name']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no NaNs, use `json_normalize`.

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.name.tolist())['Name']

0    Kevin
1    Scott
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

---

If there are NaNs, you will need to drop them first. However, it is easy to retain the indices.

```
df

   emp_id                                               name
0   101.0  {'Name': 'Kevin', 'attributes': {'type': 'Cont...
1   102.0                                                NaN
2   103.0  {'Name': 'Scott', 'attributes': {'type': 'Cont...

idx = df.index[df.name.notna()]
names = pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.name.dropna().tolist())['Name']  
names.index = idx
```

```
names

0    Kevin
2    Scott
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. Looks like the dictionary format is different in my source as compared to the edit made.. Data I have is as {'attributes': {'type': 'Contact', 'url': '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact/00985300000bt4HEG4'}, 'Name': 'Kevin'} .. On trying the above, I get an error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'"

Comment: @scottmartin I hope you tried the solution that comes after the "if there are NaNs..." part?

Comment: If I may ask for one more help, I am trying to add this to the existing Dataframe and I did the below:

idx = df.index[df.name.notna()]
df['names'] = pd.io.json.json_normalize(name().tolist())['Name']  

But when I try to do

df['names'].index = idx.  I get an error ValueError: Length mismatch

Comment: @scottmartin Just need to do `idx = df.index[df.name.notna()]; names = pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.name.dropna().tolist())['Name'] ; names.index = idx; df['new_col'] = names`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply`, and use `tolist` to make it a list:

```
print(df['name'].apply(lambda x: x.get('Name')).tolist())
```

Output:

```
['Kevin', 'Scott']
```

If don't need list, want `Series`, use:

```
print(df['name'].apply(lambda x: x.get('Name')))
```

Output:

```
0    Kevin
1    Scott
Name: name, dtype: object
```

**Update:**

```
print(df['name'].apply(lambda x: x['attributes'].get('Name')).tolist())
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Looks like the dictionary format is different in my source as compared to the edit made..  Data I have is as 

{'attributes': {'type': 'Contact', 'url': '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact/00985300000bt4HEG4'}, 'Name': 'Kevin'}

Comment: I still get an error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"

Comment: @scottmartin Now?

Comment: it returned "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable".. Could you please assist..

Answer (score 0):

Try following line:

```
names = [name.get('Name') for name in df['name']]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, get an error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'